# There's a way of create this sequence of Streams?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to implement this marble diagram, with the hipotesis of have a N number of sN$, and I'm adding this streams to the main$.

```
s1$    +--1--------------------99--------------------->
s2$    +------3--------7------------------------------>

main$  +---[1]-[1, 3]---[1, 7]---[99, 7]-------------->
```

Right now I have a aproximation, but with the "repetitions"

```
const main$ = new Rx.Subject()
const s1$ = new Rx.Subject()
const s2$ = new Rx.Subject()

main$
  .scan((a, c) => [...a, c], [])
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v))

s1$.subscribe(x => main$.onNext(x))
s2$.subscribe(x => main$.onNext(x))    

s1$.onNext(3)
s2$.onNext(1)

s1$.onNext(6)
s2$.onNext(44)

/*
  Expect:
    [3]
    [3, 1]
    [6, 1]
    [6, 44]
*/

/*
  What I have:
     [3]
     [3, 1]
     [3, 1, 6]
     [3, 1, 6, 44]
*/
```

There's a way of doing this? 
Also I tried to add the streams sN$ into main$:

```
const main$ = new Rx.Subject()
const s1$ = new Rx.Subject()
const s2$ = new Rx.Subject()

main$
  .mergeAll()
  .scan((a, c) => [...a, c], [])
  .subscribe(
    (v) => console.log(v)
  )

main$.onNext(s1$)
main$.onNext(s2$)

s1$.onNext(3)
s2$.onNext(1)

s1$.onNext(6)
s2$.onNext(44)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html). While that still require every stream to start with a value, you can prefix a `null` value to make every stream start with something using [startWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html).

```
const source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  s1.startWith(void 0),
  s2.startWith(void 0),
  s3.startWith(void 0),
  (s1, s2, s3) => [s1, s2, s3])
```

Optional you can remove `undefined` values from the resulting array.

Now, we can extend that to work with a variable list of streams. Credits to @xgrommx.

```
main$
 .scan((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
 .switch(obs => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs))
```

We can also use `c.shareReplay(1)` to make streams remember there last value when we `switch`. That however, wont combine with `c.startWith(void 0)`, so we can use either one or the other.

Example:

```js
    const main$ = new Rx.Subject()
    const s1$ = new Rx.Subject(1)
    const s2$ = new Rx.Subject(1)
    const s3$ = new Rx.Subject(1)
    const s4$ = new Rx.Subject(1)

    main$
     .scan((a, c) => a.concat(c.shareReplay(1)), [])
     .map(obs => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs))
     .switch()
     .map(v => v.filter(e => !!e))
     .map(v => v.join(','))
     .subscribe(v => $('#result').append('<br>' + v))

    main$.onNext(s1$)
    s1$.onNext(1)
    main$.onNext(s2$)
    s2$.onNext(void 0) // Since we can't use startWith
    main$.onNext(s3$)
    s3$.onNext(5)
    s1$.onNext(55)
    s2$.onNext(12)
    s2$.onNext(14)
    s3$.onNext(6)
    main$.onNext(s4$)
    s4$.onNext(999)
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve finally the problem with some filter the nulls that I begin on the `startWith()`:

```
main$
  .scan((a, c) => [...a, c.startWith(null).shareReplay(1)], [])
  .map(obs => Observable.combineLatest(obs))
  .switch()
  .map((x) => x.filter((x) => x != null))
  .filter((x) => x.length)
```

Looks un-readable (as any sequence of Rx, but If you draw the marble makes totally sense!)

Comment: Why do u use "startWith"?

Comment: Maybe you can use smth like

`js
main$
  .scan((a, c) => [...a, c.startWith(null).shareReplay(1)], [])
  .map(obs => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs).map(x => x.filter(Boolean)).filter(x => x.length))
  .switch()
`

Comment: For begin the current subjects inside the array with some value for be able to combineLatest with something (in this case is null). Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but for is only moving functional operations on the stream, and filtering after the switch makes more sense to me.