# RxJS need shareReplay with default value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The problem is that `startWith` and `shareReplay` combine poorly.

If you use `source.startWith(0).shareReplay(1)`, new subscriptions will always start with `0` , and `shareReplay` is meaningless, `source.shareReplay(1).startWith(0)` works slightly better, but result in new subscriptions to receive two values.

Expected:

```
source ---1---2----3---4----5
ob1    0--1---2----3---4----5
ob2             2--3---4----5
```

Update: Seems like my minimized case was too minimized. My problem is that i switch from `ob1` to `ob2` using `switch`, what means `ob1` will unsubscribe right before `ob2` subscribes. Weirdly enough it does work correctly if i use just `shareReplay(1)`, but the combination of `startWith(0).shareReplay(1)` does not.

```
const main$ = new Rx.Subject()
const s1$ = new Rx.Subject()


// Expected:
// 0 1 2 2 3 4

//const s2$ = s1$.shareReplay(1).startWith(0)
// got: 
// 0 1 2 0 2 3 4

//const s2$ = s1$.startWith(0).shareReplay(1)
// got:
// 0 1 2 2 0 3 4

const s2$ = s1$.shareReplay(1)
// got:
// 1 2 2 3 4

main$.switch()
  .subscribe(
    v => console.log("1: " + v)
  )

main$.onNext(s2$)
s1$.onNext(1)
s1$.onNext(2)

main$.onNext(s2$)

s1$.onNext(3)
s1$.onNext(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your problem, I put up a jsfiddle: cf. http://jsfiddle.net/qvb3xbqz/2/.

```
var counter = 0;
 var validation$ = Rx.Observable
 .fromEvent(document.getElementById('validation'), 'click')
 .map(function(){return ++counter})
 .do(emits(ta_validation, 'First subscription'))
 .startWith(0)
 .shareReplay(1);

setTimeout(function (){
  validation$.do(emits(ta_change, 'second subscription')).subscribe(function(){})
}, 1000);
```

One subscription is immediately subscribed. Second subscription kicks in after 1s. You will see that they behave as expected. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Funny, i cant reproduce it in a simple scenario, but my problem was including using `Switch`. I've wrote an example here: https://jsbin.com/jijediduga/1/edit?js,console

Comment: You’r problem could be that the shareReplay returns a single subscription?

Comment: Your problem might be with your use of `switch`. `switch` seems similar to `flatMapLatest` and if it works the same, it should unsubscribe from the current observable source, and subscribe to the new one. That might explain why you restart from the beginning each time? In any case, `shareReplay` seems to be working fine, you should review the behaviour of the operators you are using. Also, just in case, which version of Rxjs are you using?

Comment: @user3743222 Sorry, stackoverflow gave no warning about your reply, missed it. I would be fine with both RxJS 4 or 5, not asking version specific.

Comment: Dorus, the combination of operators does exactly what it is supposed to. It unsubscribes for s2, then resubscribes to s2 which is `s1$.startWith(0)`, and hence you get a 0 once again. Then `s1$` kicks, and because s1$ is hot (as all subjects are), it continues where it was i.e. with 3 and 4. So there is nothing strange here. If what you mention in your answer as expected is what you want to achieve, then there is no need to use `switch`. Just use `source.startWith(0).shareReplay(1)`

Comment: @user3743222 But i do need switch, there is an underlying requiremnt for that. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132479/theres-a-way-of-create-this-sequence-of-streams/36133038#36133038). I never claimed the operators do not do what they promise, only that they do not do what i want them to do ;)

Comment: To state my problem simple: I need it to work like an [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because in the switch operation, `s2$` is unsubscribed, which causes `shareReply` unsubscribe from the upstream pipeline. `s2$` is then immediately re-subscribed, which causes `shareReplay` to replay the `2` and then re-subscribe to the upstream pipeline, re-executing the `startWith`.

In the mean time, rxjs changed. `shareReplay` by default no longer unsubscribes the upstream pipeline even when there is no downstream subscriber. If you require `shareReplay` to unsubscribe the upstream pipeline, you can enable this as an option by setting `refCount: true`.

Furthermore, if `shareReplay` unsubscribed from the upstream pipeline due to `refCount: true`, it does no longer buffer the reply of the old upstream pipeline. This will prevent the confusing repeated `2` before the `0` in example provided by the OP.

See this update example:

```js
import { startWith, shareReplay, Subject, switchAll } from 'rxjs';

const main$ = new Subject()
const s1$ = new Subject()

// const s2$ = s1$.pipe(shareReplay(1),startWith(0))
// got: 
// 0 1 2 0 2 3 4

//const s2$ = s1$.pipe(shareReplay({bufferSize:1, refCount: true}),startWith(0))
// got: 
// 0 1 2 0 3 4

const s2$ = s1$.pipe(startWith(0), shareReplay(1))
// got:
// 0 1 2 2 3 4

//const s2$ = s1$.pipe(startWith(0), shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true}))
// got:
// 0 1 2 0 3 4

main$.pipe(switchAll())
  .subscribe(
    v => console.log("1: " + v)
  )

main$.next(s2$)
s1$.next(1)
s1$.next(2)

main$.next(s2$)

s1$.next(3)
s1$.next(4)
```