# How to setup an RxJS.Observable.timer() with a due date

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an authentication system here which has several information, including an `expires_in` property, declared in seconds. This informs when the token generated will be expired and, to handle this I'm using the concept of an `RxJS.Observable`.

With the `expires_in` value, I calculate the expiration date generating a `Date` object, incrementing it's value with the expiration, and getting it's time with `getTime()`, in milisseconds, and with this I have the due date.

When I declare the `RxJS.Observable`, I'm doing like this:

```
// The code is shortened to the relevant part

let obs = Observable.timer(dueVar) // Which is in milisseconds
    .subscribe(
        (x) => console.log(x),
        (x) => console.log(x),
        () => console.log('Expired') // onComplete, right? Only this one matters to me...
    );
```

I've tried to put, where is `dueVar`, the `Date` object, but no success at all... The snippet throws the first parameter of the `subscribe()` function as `0 [Number]`, and immediately throws `Expired`, which is the last param.

How can I make this operation? I didn't any relevant explanation for that matter... The second parameter, as I saw on the docs, it's optional, and for call the `onNext` callback every span time that is declared there. But I need to dispatch this one time only.

Comment: Could you make a marble diagram with sample input  and expected output? Seems like you could use the `delay` operator

Comment: Why do you say you have a `dueVar` which is a date object but in the code you say that it is in milliseconds?

Comment: @paulpdaniels It's was a typo, I will fix the question, but in the docs they say that the first argument can be an positive integer or a Date object.

Comment: @user3743222 I really don't know what this is. Can you give me more details?

Comment: @MateusDuartePoncedeLeon It will make a difference because the time in milliseconds refers to a relative time from _now_. Whereas if you pass a date it refers to an absolute point in time, and if that date is in the past it will fire immediately.

Comment: Here is an example of marble diagram : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132479/theres-a-way-of-create-this-sequence-of-streams/36135506#36135506. It is basically your input and output streams on a timeline.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem was simply solved by @paulpdaniels explanation over the details of the method.

Answer (score 0):

On the comments, it became more clear what I needed to do.

I was considering the time in an absolute way, but if I'll use milisseconds, as @paulpdaniels stated, the time need to be relative from *now*, which makes a huge difference.

So, despite informing the argument with the entire timestamp from 1970's, I only need to use the `expires_in` property, times 1000, to transform it from seconds to milisseconds.